How can I replace text "There are no events in this range." with my own component in react-big-calendar?
When using "react-big-calendar" I need to place an image with text for "no events" state in agenda view. By default, it shows "There are no events in this range."
Is there any way to do this?

I tried to find any information, but failed. I use react and styled-components
